# Insert data from file to sqlite in android

Tags: android, performance

I have file that contain insert statements like

```
INSERT INTO MyTable1 VALUES(31402,33,1332602460,0.72,'Description');

INSERT INTO MyTable2 VALUES(31402,33,1332602460,0.72,'Description', 'Name');
```

File contain 44667 lines.

What is the best way to insert this file in database of the android?

Read line by line and insert or something else?

Comment: Your example might be made up for this question. But if `MyTable2` contains 85% of the same data that `MyTable1` has, you can: 1) delete `MyTable1` and use a select statement on `MyTable2` without the last column, or 2) use foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

1. disable indexes. Google it how to do it if you don't know, that is another question
2. insert all lines (execute your SQL)
3. enable indexes

it is always faster to insert into a table which has no indexes, than having indexes.